# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^m\left(D(g_i){\bf{x}}, D(g_i){\bf{y}}\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^m D^{\dagger}(g_i)D(g_i){\bf{x}},{\bf{y}}\right)$

Tags: proof-explanation, representation-theory, quantum-mechanics

I am reading "Applications of group theory in quantum mechanics" by M.I. Petrashen & E.D. Trifonov. In chapter 3, section 3.4 - Existence of an equivalent unitary representation, on page 29, I am stuck on equation (3.32) which states that
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\left(D(g_i){\bf{x}}, D(g_i){\bf{y}}\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^m D^{\dagger}(g_i)D(g_i){\bf{x}},{\bf{y}}\right)\tag{3.32}$$
Petrashen clearly states that the $D(g_i)$ are representation matrices and denotes the scalar product as
$$({\bf{x}},{\bf{y}})=x_1\overline{y_1}+ x_2\overline{y_2}+\cdots + x_n\overline{y_n}\tag{A}$$
Where $\overline{y_i}$ is (presumably) the complex conjugate, ${y_i}^\ast$.

The sum of scalar products is,
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\left(D(g_i){\bf{x}}, D(g_i){\bf{y}}\right)$$

$$=D(g_1)x_1 D^\ast(g_1){y_1}^{\ast}+D(g_2)x_2D^\ast(g_2){y_2}^{\ast}+\cdots +D(g_m)x_mD^\ast(g_m){y_m}^{\ast}\tag{B}$$
I don't understand how equation $(3.32)$ was deduced, as taking the Hermitian adjoint/conjugate of both sides of $(\mathrm{B})$ yields,

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\left(D(g_i){\bf{x}}, D(g_i){\bf{y}}\right)\right)^\dagger$$

$$=\Big(D(g_1){x_1}D^\ast(g_1){y_1}^{\ast}\Big)^{\dagger}+\Big(D(g_2)x_2D^\ast(g_2){y_2}^{\ast}\Big)^\dagger+\cdots +\Big(D(g_m)x_mD^\ast(g_m){y_m}^{\ast}\Big)^\dagger$$

$$=(D^\dagger (g_1){x_1}^\ast {D^\ast}^{\dagger}(g_1) y_1+ D^\dagger (g_2){x_2}^\ast {D^\ast}^{\dagger} (g_2)^\dagger y_2+\cdots + D^\dagger (g_m){x_m}^{\ast} {D^\ast}^{\dagger} (g_m) y_m$$
I don't know how to proceed from here to show that this is equal to

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m D^{\dagger}(g_i)D(g_i){\bf{x}},{\bf{y}}\right)$$

I am reading another book by Michael Tinkham called "Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics", which in pdf form can be found [here](http://www.infis.ufu.br/%7Egerson/grupos/1%20-%20Main%20Books/Tinkham%20-%20Group%20Theory%20and%20Quantum%20Mechanics.pdf) and in Appendix A, page 317 (or page 327 if viewing online/electronically), Tinkham denotes the inner product or Hermitian scalar product as
$$({\bf{v}},{\bf{w}})=\sum_k v_k^\ast w_k.$$ For reasons I don't understand the complex conjugation is in the *opposite* order to the way in which Petrashen denotes the scalar product in $(\mathrm{A})$ (where the second vector is complex conjugated).
but even with that adjustment, this is still not equal to the RHS of $(3.32)$,
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m D^{\dagger}(g_i)D(g_i){\bf{x}},{\bf{y}}\right)$$

I'm missing something here, can someone please explain how I can show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\left(D(g_i){\bf{x}}, D(g_i){\bf{y}}\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^m D^{\dagger}(g_i)D(g_i){\bf{x}},{\bf{y}}\right)\tag{3.32}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look up the reference, but presumably the Hermitian form is defined so that $\langle u, Mv\rangle = \langle M^\dagger u, v\rangle$ for any matrix $M$. In that case you just have
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \langle D(g_i) \mathbf{x}, D(g_i) \mathbf{y}\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m \langle D(g_i)^\dagger D(g_i) \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle = \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^m D(g_i)^\dagger D(g_i) \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\right\rangle.$$

Your equation (B) does not make sense. The use of $x_i$ and $y_i$ is not appropriate.

Whether a Hermitian form is conjugate-linear in the first or second argument is inconsistent across the literature. You'll often have to reverse the order to fix things up to be compatible across sources.

**Edit in response to follow-up comment:** The identity $\langle u, Mv\rangle = \langle M^\dagger u, v\rangle$ is the usual abstract definition of $M^\dagger$, where $\langle -, -\rangle$ is a fixed non-degenerate Hermitian form. It's very easy to find sources that take this view, like [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint).

You can also prove it directly using the usual coordinate-based definition. If $(M^\dagger)_{ij}$ is defined to be $\overline{M_{ji}}$, then:

\begin{align*}
  \langle u, Mv\rangle &= \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \overline{(Mv)_i} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \overline{\sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij} v_j} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \sum_{j=1}^n \overline{M_{ij}} \overline{v_j} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \sum_{j=1}^n (M^\dagger)_{ji} \overline{v_j} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i (M^\dagger)_{ji} \overline{v_j} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n (\sum_{i=1}^n (M^\dagger)_{ji} u_i) \overline{v_j} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n (M^\dagger u)_j \overline{v_j} \\
&= \langle M^\dagger u, v\rangle.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your first term on the right-hand side of (B) is $x_1 D(g_i) D(g_i)^* y_1^*$. This has many errors--for one thing, it's a product of two matrices and two scalars, so it's a matrix, so it's not of the correct type. That first term should be $(D(g_i) \mathbf{x})_1 \overline{(D(g_i) \mathbf{y})_1} + \cdots + (D(g_i) \mathbf{x})_n \overline{(D(g_i) \mathbf{y})_n}$. Your equation (A) uses commas instead of plus signs. I didn't check your other expressions. It seems to me you would benefit from more care in making sure algebraic expressions actually do match up perfectly.

Comment: I've added discussion about the adjoint identity, including an elementary direct proof using the usual coordinate-based approach. Your updated version of (B) continues to have many fatal errors. I'm getting some sense that you may be reading material that is too advanced for you currently. You should probably at least get some guidance, e.g. by doing a reading course.

Comment: I understand all of your proof except this part: $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i (M^\dagger)_{ji} \overline{v_j}
= \sum_{j=1}^n \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n (M^\dagger)_{ji} u_i \Big) \overline{v_j}$.  What allowed you to interchange the order of those summations ($i$, and $j$)?

Comment: That's just using commutativity of addition. Try writing it out for $n=2$ and it will be clear.

Comment: Okay LHS $=\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 u_i (M^\dagger)_{ji} \overline{v_j}=u_1(M^\dagger)_{11}\overline{v_1}+u_1(M^\dagger)_{21}\overline{v_2}+u_2(M^\dagger)_{12}\overline{v_1}+u_2(M^\dagger)_{22}\overline{v_2}$

RHS=$\sum_{j=1}^2 \Big(\sum_{i=1}^2 (M^\dagger)_{ji} u_i \Big) \overline{v_j}
=(M^\dagger)_{11}u_1\overline{v_1}+(M^\dagger)_{12}u_2\overline{v_1}+(M^\dagger)_{21}u_1\overline{v_2}+(M^\dagger)_{22}u_2\overline{v_2}$ these equal only if I can commute the $(M^\dagger)_{ij}$ and $u_i$ which I can because $u_i$ is a vector and $(M^\dagger)_{ij}$ is a matrix element. This correct?